# Quickbooks PHP integration with custom database schema

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Using the ever-so-handy QuickBooks DevKit by [consolibyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26133/keith-palmer-consolibyte) v3, I've successfully been able to use the examples of 'mirroring' the QB database in MySQL, following the quick-start guides and the information within the wiki.

My problem comes when trying to do something different than 'mirroring' the data. Instead of qb_invoices I have my own `Invoice` table, for example.

How can I make this happen? Looking through the examples, everything calls `initialize()` and `createUser()` to mirror all the database tables. Ultimately I'd like to leverage the DevKit, especially with its integration with WebConnect and Online, but without the "entire" QuickBooks database included.

I've thought of a couple of things, maybe I'm on the right track?

- Write my own SOAP server to communicate with WebConnect, sending qbXML back/forth and interpreting the results on my own to figure out what data gets inserted into what tables in my custom schema
- Modify the QuickBooks DevKit to fit my needs - hook in somewhere and have it write data to my custom schema
- Hybrid approach - use the DevKit to facilitate a SOAP server but make it write to my own schema

Comment: Well, one thing in my favor ... just figured out I can set `quickbooks_sql_enabled` to false in the example and it *doesn't* set up all the crazy mirroring. A step in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make this happen?

If you don't want to use the SQL mirroring, then don't start with the SQL mirroring example.

Use the default quick-start files (docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php) and the quick-start guide instead. Links:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php
- Quick-start for QuickBooks WINDOWS: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start
- Quick-start for QuickBooks ONLINE: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start

> especially with its integration with WebConnect and Online

There is no such thing as "WebConnect". There's the QuickBooks Web Connector (for QuickBooks for WINDOWS -- it is *not* used for QuickBooks ONLINE).

> Write my own SOAP server to communicate with WebConnect, sending qbXML back/forth and interpreting the results on my own to figure out what data gets inserted into what tables in my custom schema

You don't need to write your own SOAP server -- we've already done this for you. Start with the quick-start guide I've linked to above -- all of this has already been done for you.

> Modify the QuickBooks DevKit to fit my needs - hook in somewhere and have it write data to my custom schema

Start with the quick-start guide above. If you're making code modifications to the library files themselves (instead of just the examples of how to use it), you're doing something wrong. It has hooks and plugins built in specifically so that you *don't* need to modify it.

> Hybrid approach - use the DevKit to facilitate a SOAP server but make it write to my own schema

This is essentially what the quick-start I linked to above does, and is the way you're intended to use the libraries.

Comment: Keith, I had a feeling you'd answer -- thanks! So, after I had asked the question, I started to wrap my head around the framework and how it works. Specifically, the process of QBWC connecting, asking for requests, and sending responses. I've had to work this project from the SQL-mapping backwards, so it's been a bit rought getting my head around the whole thing. Thanks for your information, and I appreciate the answer! It's a great framework, it's just taken me a bit to connect the dots. :)